# How synchronized block is handled in a clustered environment

Tags: java

By  clustered environment I mean same code running on multiple server machines.My scenario what I can think of is as follows

Multiple request come to update Card details based on expiry time from different threads at the same time. A snippet of code is following

```
synchronized(card) { //card object
if(card.isExpired())
updateCard()
}
```

My understanding is synchronized block works at jvm level so how in multiserver environment it is achieved.

Please suggest edit to rephrase question. I asked what I can recollect from a question asked to me.

Comment: This is seriously hard to answer in general. You might want to add more information on the problem you are trying to solve (a global lock is probably not a good idea performancewise) as to enable more specific answers.

Comment: In a clustered (and in fact, even in a non-clustered environment), you won't rely on synchronization, but on transaction isolation, and database pessimistic or optimistic locking.

Comment: When you lock an object, you lock the object which is in that JVM.  The JVM has no idea you intended to lock all instance of that object across all JVMs.

Answer (score 5):

As you said, synchronized block is only for "local JVM" threads.
When it comes to cluster, it is up to you how you drive your distributed transaction.

It really depends where your objects (e.g. card) are stored.

- Database - You will probably need to use some locking strategy. Very likely optimistic locking that stores a version of entity and checks it when every change is made. Or more "safe" pessimistic locking where you lock the whole row when making changes.
- Memory - You will probably need some memory grid solution (e.g. Hazelcast...) and make use of its transaction support or implement it by yourself
- Any other? You will have specify...

Answer (score 3):

See, in a clustered environment, you will usually have multiple JVMs running the same code. If traffic is high, then actually the number of JVMs could auto-scale and increase (new instances could be spawned). This is one of the reasons why you should be really careful when using static fields to keep data in a distributed environment.

Next, coming to your actual question, if you have a single jvm serving requests, then all other threads will have to wait to get that lock. If you have multiple JVMs running, then lock acquired by one thread on oneJVM will not prevent acquisition of the (in reality, not same, but conceptually same) lock by another thread in a different jvm.

Comment: Yeah, beacuse syncronized block is JVM related, not environment related.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to handle that only one thread can edit the object or perform the action (based on the method name i.e updatecard) I suggest you implement optimistic locking (versioning), hibernate can do this quite easily, to prevent  dirty read.